# Stopping all the instances of a specific region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I want to stop the instances of a specific region let say us-east-1 every night, though i don't want to specify  the instance id. Rather, I would like to stop all the instances present in the region. I am using the following code. What changes can i make in the code?

```
import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78g9h', 'i-08ce9b2d7eccf6d26']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the instance id's and then stop them -

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Values': ['running']}])
instance_ids = [instance.id for instance in instances]
ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance_ids).stop()
```

See boto documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#checking-what-instances-are-running)